# Can't understand nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that Nodejs is supposed to be different to other laguages due to the *event loop*, what makes it difficult to understand at first. However there's no way I can understand the following code (I managed to make it work, but no logic explanation).

I create new instances of a SSH connection each time I receive an special request, let's say:

```
sshCons = {};

sshObjt = new Connection();
sshCons[request_id] = sshObjt;
sshObjt.connect(); //and son on...
```

So I create a new Connection and "store" it in what we can understand as an "associative array", even if I think that it's just an Object that carries properties and their values.
The question is, if I place this code after the lines written above:

```
sshObjt.on('data', function() {
    // CODE
});
```

How does Node know which `sshObjt` is the one that emits the event if I created multiple `sshObjt`s and "stored" them? I previously tried to loop over the `sshCons` object but that shouldn't be the appropriate way of handling this. In case I'm wrong, which should be the proper way of handling events of multiple objects "stored" in `sshCons` object?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but chances are that in the callback `this` will refer to the emitting "sshObjt".

Comment: That makes sense. But the thing is, as I "make new `sshObjt`s" constantly and therefore "overwrite" the last created sshObjt, I thought Node would only attend the *data* event of the latest created `sshObjt`. I hope I could explain myself

Comment: You overwrite the variable, you do not manipulate the object itself that was stored there

Comment: Although you are overwriting the `sshObjt`, you are assigning it with the event handler for `data` event at the moment you create it. The current instance of `sshObjt` is assigned with it's own even handler. It is more of a javascript question in general than node. :)

Comment: Thanks to Patric and Maverick. Your explanations where completely eye opening, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kay says, `this` has a decent chance to be the object that triggered the event; but that is up to whoever wrote the code for `Connection`. If it does not, it might be giving the handler an argument that has the receiver. (You are not giving any details as to where `Connection` comes from, so we can't check for you what exactly it does and doesn't provide.) If all else fails, and the library designer failed to provide the receiving object anywhere, you can create a closure:

```
sshObjt.on('data',
  (function(receiver) {
    return function() {
      // CODE where `receiver` is correct
    };
  })(sshObjt)
);
```

As to the worry from your comment to `Kay`, that is unfounded. When you attach a handler to an object, you attach the handler to the *object* - not to the variable that contains it. It's just like this:

```
var annas_husband = { name: "Tim", occupation: "mechanic" }
var joeys_dad = annas_husband;
joeys_dad.occupation = "supervisor";
annas_husband // => { name: "Tim", occupation: "supervisor" }
```

You didn't change `joeys_dad`'s occupation. You changed Tim's. Since both `annas_husband` and `joeys_dad` are Tim, it happens to both. And conversely, which pertains to your case:

```
var guy;
var guys = [];

guy = { name: "Jake", occupation: "mechanic" }
guys.push(guy);

guy = { name: "Tim", occupation: "mechanic" }
guys.push(guy);
guy.occupation = "supervisor"

guy = { name: "Jeff", occupation: "mechanic" }
guys.push(guy);

guys
// => [
//      { name: "Jake", occupation: "mechanic" },
//      { name: "Tim", occupation: "supervisor" }
//      { name: "Jeff", occupation: "mechanic" },
//    ]
```

Here, again, you didn't change `guy`'s occupation, you changed Tim's. Jake and Jeff weren't the `guy` at that time, so they did not get the promotion. `on` works exactly the same way - it attaches an event to an object, regardless in which variable the object resides currently, or in the future.

Comment: "When you attach a handler to an object, you attach the handler to the object - not to the variable that contains it" This was pretty much the sentence I've been looking for. Thanks. The library is ssh2 from mscdex https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Comment: Then I think you have a logic error in your code: `Connection` does not emit `data`, the *streams* you get from `Connection` do. (Nothing to do with this question, just thought to mention it.)

Comment: That's right, I didn't want to complicate the question explaining `stream` was an object that came from `sshObjt.shell()` ... I tried to make it simple and apply to the context of *data* event. Anyway I could have made the example with a *connected* event which is really emitted by the object (I guess)